# MongoDB match by field in document's array if it exists, if not -> skip match by this field

Tags: mongodb, go, match, aggregation, mgo

I've got collection named 'banners'.
If user choosed Continent and Country the body of this document will be:

```
 "Continents" : [ 
     4, 
     6
 ],
 "Countries" : [ 
     "74d06620-79b1-4449-9a17-848169d514ce"
 ]
```

But, if user choosed all Countries in this Continent:

```
 "Continents" : [ 
     4, 
     6
 ],
 "Countries" : [],
```

How can i match in aggregation by field in document's array if it exists, if not -> skip match by this field and continue searching? 
Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: The field still exists - it's an empty array, so just add an $or where [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) is 0.

Comment: @AlexBlex, I love u)
The request is:
db.banners.find({"$or": [{"Countries": "e227925b-a722-40a7-b599-8c44afbb3cd5"}, {"Countries": {"$size": 0}}]})

Comment: It definitely is, but it's not aggregation. The docs for the $size you are using is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/index.html).